# Include somthing.html in XML file

Tags: html, xml, include-path

How could you include a html file in a xml file, not html code but a html file for example.

**something.xml**

```
<question_passage>
                include href="../information/something.html"
            </question_passage>
```

**something.html**

```
    <div>
some code
</div>
```

The reason i need to do this is because ill be using something.html text content over and over and its easier to reference one file that duplicate the text over and over. It can be a .text file not a .html as its will just be text.
Thanks.

**What I have tried**

**XML file**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE doc [<!ENTITY testSYSTEM "path/test.html">]>

            <test>
                &test;
            </test>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the HTML is also valid XML You could use [XInclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) to include an XML file within another.